# How can i take the first data from arraylist(matches in my code)

Tags: android

I need to show only the first entry from `Arraylist`.

My code below shows all the results but I need only the first entry from the list.

`wordsList` is the name of `ListView`:

```
ArrayList <<String>> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

wordsList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,matches));
```

---

Full method code:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
    { 
        // Populate the wordsList with the String values the recognition engine thought it heard 
        ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra( RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS); 
        wordsList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, matches.get(0)));
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "first data" mean? Do you mean the first element of the `ArrayList`?

Comment: From what user1543340 is asking in the first statement, that is the question. However, user1543340 mentions the `ListView` which is throwing me off a little.

Comment: error is "The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(VoiceRecognitionDemo, int, String) is undefined"

Comment: What is the error you are getting with the "Full method code" that was posted? Please include it in your original post.

Comment: http://www.jameselsey.co.uk/blogs/techblog/android-how-to-implement-voice-recognition-a-nice-easy-tutorial/ here the full code it shows all the element but i need only first

Comment: Ok, try my answer again. I believe i may have found your problem. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: So, the error you posted `The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(VoiceRecognitionDemo, int, String) is undefined` is that from the code you tried from the answers, or is that the error you are getting from your original attempt you posted in your original post? Also, if you only want the first element, why use a `ListView` and an `Adapter`? Just use a `TextView` or something.

Comment: @prolink007 i try but it doesn't work.may be you can check.pls i need it

Comment: OK, now try my answer. Not sure why you would want to do this, but it will probably work.

Comment: String m=RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS.toString();
            wordsList.setText(""+m);

i modify code like that "it show the result android.speech.extra.RESULT"  @prolink007

Comment: And i try this but the result show null
""String m = data.getStringExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        wordsList.setText(""+m);""  wordlist is the name of edittext @prolink007

Comment: Your previous two comments are very confusing and do not seem to relate to your original question. Have you tried the new contents of my answer? If so, please let me know the results. If not, please try it. Your previous two comments are confusing me even more about your actual question.

Comment: i understood like that"don't use arraylist and listview,use textview and i try it but it show 'null'"from your answer.    String m = data.getStringExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS).toString();
      
        wordsList.setText(""+m);   wordlist is the name of textview @prolink007

Comment: Well at this point, you need to verify the data you are getting from the `Intent`. Step through it and see what the actual `String` is for that `Intent`

Comment: i dis't understand your solution.Please explain more,or can you fix the code.did the your solution ""String a=RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS.toString();
         String m = data.getStringExtra(a).toString();"" @prolink007

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are only wanting the first element from the `ArrayList<String> matches` then you just need to create a new `List<String>` and add the first element to the new `List`.

Then use that new `List` for the `Adapter`.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) { 
        // Populate the wordsList with the String values the recognition engine thought it heard 
        ArrayList<String> matches = 
                data.getStringArrayListExtra( RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

        if (matches.size() > 0) {
            List<String> oneMatch = new ArrayList<String>();
            oneMatch.add(matches.get(0));

            wordsList.setAdapter(
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                     this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, oneMatch));
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Matches does not contain any values.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the error in your original post? Also, can you please clarify what you are wanting? Your question is very difficult to understand. Read the comments that have been posted.

Comment: i try but it give error.here the full olf class  

' protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            // Populate the wordsList with the String values the recognition engine thought it heard
            ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                    RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            wordsList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    matches.get(0)));
       
        }'

Comment: May be the matches return is empty. Check if matches.size() is greater than zero and add to oneMatch list.

Comment: Added the fail check in there.

Comment: @prolink007 ok sir,your code is working clearly.you are perfect thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the first element of the `ArrayList` then you need to use the `get(int)` method of the ArrayList class. So in your case `matches.get(0)` would get you the first element of the `matches` `ArrayList`. Please clarify what you mean by "first data" so I can provide the best answer possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to show the first item, then do something like this:

```
ArrayList <<String>> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

wordsList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,matches.get(0)));
```

Changing it to `matches.get(0)` makes it only pass the first String object in the list to your adapter.  Hard to tell what you are doing though, as it seems inefficient to have an adapter with only one item in it.

Comment: i try but it give error.here the full olf class  
'
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            // Populate the wordsList with the String values the recognition engine thought it heard
            ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                    RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            wordsList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    matches.get(0)));
          
      }'

Comment: Please summarize the error for us or post it in your original post, this way it is easier to read. It is very difficult to read code "in-lined". And please clarify your question.

Comment: You should only call `setAdapter()` once, typically in `onCreate()`.  If you want to change the data to an adapter, then do it directly through the adapter and then make sure to call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: This will not work, because the constructor needs a `List<String>` not just a `String`.

Comment: Ah, I thought there was an overload for a single item.  A solution would be to use the `ArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId)` constructor and then just call `add(matches.get(0))` with `notifyDataSetChanged()`